# Is there a generic term for origin and destination seen from an airport point of view?

Tags: airport, terminology

I am trying to create a program that gives you the departures or the arrivals from a given airport.

Thus, in the software code, I would like to refer to both `origin` and`destination` with the same term, in order to print the former if the user requested arrivals, and the latter if the user requested departures.

So basically I want to know if there is a common name for these two terms, when speaking from the airport point of view, i.e. referring to a generic flight, regardless of it being inbound or outbound, what is "the other airport" in the jargon?

Comment: Do you want to use this term when displaying the output, or just for the code?

Comment: Why not just use "airport", it's already a generic term that could be an origin or a destination.

Comment: @Geoff No doubt "airport" will already be used to refer to the base airport being searched. This might be a question better suited to Stack Overflow; nevertheless I'll throw in my two cents and suggest a simple solution being HomeAirport and AwayAirport. I don't think there's a universal term so I doubt you'll get a concrete answer.

Comment: On English.SE: [Word for an Origin and Destination without regard for route](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/125178/70063)

Comment: Thanks for the link foot, and regarding your question, I just need it for the code, so the end user won't see it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the “remote” airport — that should work for both arrivals and departures.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I really like remote as an option

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a way to sort and select flights, consisting of a departing airport and an arriving airport. An airport is a node in the directed graph of flights, and its meaning is predicated on whether you are looking for arrivals or departures.

`Departing           Flight                    Arriving
Airport[1]----------Flight[1]---------------->Airport[2]`

If you are looking for a word to call the airport you aren't at (local) I could see "remote" or "external"

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I get what you mean. I was just trying to find a single comprehensible word to refactor the code, but maybe it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: For code refactoring you would get more answers over on StackOverflow or Software engineering.SE.

Answer (score 1):

The "connection" airport maybe? Could refer to where a plane is coming from, or where it's going to.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but connection to me suggests a stopover in a flight with stops. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In statistical reports, departures+ arrivals= movements

Comment: I understand that, however I understand movement more as a flight rather than as an airport. Thanks for the quick answer!